# Background Loop with Reactions Discord.Py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a background loop that will spit out an emoji every X amount of minutes with a reaction attached to it. I want for when someone presses on the reaction of the message, it will delete the message and then send another message saying "messageauthor has grabbed the loot" and then add the amount to the cash json file.

Right now, my code is making the background loop work, but I am not sure how to grab the message.author.id in regards to the background loop so I can reference it in on_reaction_add. The current code is making the bot react once when it spits out the background loop and then again in on_reaction_add. I'm trying to make it wait for a user to react to the background loop message with the same emoji and not the bot.

```
client = discord.Client()
emoji_msg_grab = {}


try:
    with open("cash.json") as fp:
        cash = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    cash = {}

def save_cash():
    with open("cash.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(cash, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_dollars(user: discord.User, dollars: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in cash:
        cash[id] = {}
    cash[id]["dollars"] = cash[id].get("dollars", 0) + dollars
    print("{} now has {} dollars".format(user.name, cash[id]["dollars"]))
    save_cash()


async def background_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        channel = client.get_channel("479919577279758340")
        emojigrab = ''
        emojimsgid = await client.send_message(channel, emojigrab)
        await client.add_reaction(emojimsgid, "")
        user_id = emojimsgid.author.id
        emoji_msg_grab[user_id] = {"emoji_msg_id": emojimsgid.id, "emoji_user_id": user_id}
        await asyncio.sleep(600)

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    msgid = reaction.message.id
    chat = reaction.message.channel

    if reaction.emoji == "" and msgid == emoji_msg_grab[user.id]["emoji_msg_id"] and user.id == emoji_msg_grab[user.id]["emoji_user_id"]:
        emoji_msg_grab[user.id]["emoji_msg_id"] = None
        await client.send_message(chat, "{} has grabbed the loot!".format(user.mention))
        await client.delete_message(reaction.message)
        add_dollars(user, 250)

client.loop.create_task(background_loop())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`Client.wait_for_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_reaction) instead of `on_reaction_add`:

```
async def background_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel("479919577279758340")
    while not client.is_closed:
        emojigrab = ''
        emojimsg = await client.send_message(channel, emojigrab)
        await client.add_reaction(emojimsg, "")
        res = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji="", message=emojimsg, timeout=600, 
                                             check=lambda reaction, user: user != client.user)
        if res:  # not None
            await client.delete_message(emojimsg)
            await client.send_message(channel, "{} has grabbed the loot!".format(res.user.mention))
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            add_dollars(res.user, 250)
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. That makes sense. I believe I'm having a problem with the bot reacting to the message itself. I have a check for on_message, but when I try to add a check within the background loops such as `if int(client.user.id) == 478423970572664853: return   else: res = await client.wait_for_reaction` it won't go past my check and do "res".

Comment: `client.user` will always be your bot, so it's id isn't likely to change.  You probably meant to check `if client.user == message.author`

Comment: Hey Patrick, yes I tried that also but got the error `undefined variable 'message'`. I am not sure how to get the message.author outside of `on_message`

Comment: @hardestchat I'm a little confused.  What message would you be checking in the background loop?

Comment: I was trying to put a check on the `emojimsg` to make sure that client.user (bot) wont be able to react to it's own message within the background loop. Right now when the bot spits out the , it makes the background loop think someone reacted to it so it's deleting the message, sending a message, and awarding the bot with `add_dollars`

Comment: You just need to add a `check` function to the `wait_for_reaction` call.  Something like `lambda reaction, user: user != client.user`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179939/discussion-between-hardestchat-and-patrick-haugh).

Comment: I apologize, I used it in a different server and it works flawlessly. Thank you!